# scroll table view inside UIScrollView in storyboard ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I always face problems with the UIScrollView which is:

I have a UIViewController that contains two tableViewControllers, the contents of these tables are bigger than the height of the iphone, so I need to use a scroller. I enable the scroll of the table, but the height of the table is big, so I need to scroll all the screen also, for this reason, I added a UIScrollView and I put these two tables inside, for now I have three scrolls, (for the two tables and for the UIScrollView).

What I need is: to allow scroll the tables with the scroll of whole screen, it means to combine the scroll of the table with the scroll of the UIScrollView.

[image]

Is there any method to combine the scrollers??

Comment: I short: You should not do that. This looks broken by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to put a UIScrollView behind the UiTableViews as the tableViews have their own scrollers. No matter how much data/cells you have in the tableView it will allow you to scroll  easily.

Comment: But not in his/her setting. There are two table views and ... It's seams just to be bad design.

Comment: yes, you are right, I removed the UIScrollView, and each table has own scroller, thank you :)

Comment: if I need to not scroll each of them alone, it means I want to scroll the tables and the whole screen by one scroll, what shall i do?

Comment: what i need is like linearlayout in android?

Comment: sorry dont know about Linear layout in android.